# uiscrollview not scrolling uiimageview

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I'm trying to insert one more image in my UIScrollView. The problem is: all my old content is still scrollable, but this image stay static in the top of the page. Does anybody know a solution?

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

  CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 109.0f);
  myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
  UIImage * img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.somelink.com"]]];
  myImage.image = img;
  myImage.opaque = YES; // explicitly opaque for performance
  [scrollView addSubview:myImage];
  [myImage release];
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your "old content" is encapsulated in a view and it's *that* view that is your UIScrollView's subview for content. If that's the case, you should add your new image to that "contentView", adjust its frame and update the scrollview's contentSize based on the new width and height of the content view.

If my guess is wrong, could you please post the code showing how the UIScrollView is created and how the "old content" is added to it?

You might also find this [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Listings/MyViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008023-MyViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6) from Apple useful with regard to the layout of subviews of a UIScrollView. (see the `- (void)layoutScrollImages` method).